# Connecting to GMail programmatically using C or Visual Basic

Tags: c, vb.net, web-services, api, gmail

I'm trying to make a small program (in either C or Visual Basic) to simply connect to a gmail email account. Then a simple if statement which will be if new mail received, label.text = "new mail" etc.

I have spent hours and hours searching and I still can't figure this out without paying for scripts.

Any help on this would be gratefully appreciated :) :)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is using the **pop3** or **imap** protocols.

1. [Examples of pop3 in Visual Basic](http://www.example-code.com/vb/pop3.asp)
2. [A GNU library for C providing a Pop3 API](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/libspopc/)

Equivalent libraries for IMAP will also be available. Your other alternative is to be a "fake browser" which logs in and scans the page for a specific HTML element such as "**inbox(3)**" but that seems messy when they provide proper protocols.

Or, my favorite approach is the **Python libgmail** library which can be found [here](http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/). Here is a little example in Python:

```
ga = libgmail.GmailAccount("google@gmail.com", "mymailismypass")
ga.login()
folder = ga.getMessagesByFolder('inbox')

for thread in folder:
  print thread.id, len(thread), thread.subject
  for msg in thread:
    print "  ", msg.id, msg.number, msg.subject
    print msg.source
```

But the code can become unstable when Google change some of their GMail setup.

Comment: Yes, count on "messy".  Gmail was designed to be viewed by a browser.  Not just a little messy either.

Comment: @nobugz, I agree. Likely half of it would go missing without JS support ;)

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a number of APIs to almost every product. Try looking for proper information on [Google Code](http://code.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a read-only data feed to view the contents of a Gmail inbox:

http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/docs/inbox_feed.html

You should be able to use that feed to get the info you need for your application.